# Solving Recurrence equation for n

Tags: recursion

I have a recurrence equation $t_n$ which is defined as

$$
t_n=2.5t_{n-1}-1.5t_{n-4},\qquad \text{for }n\geq5
$$

Where
$$
\begin{align}
t_1&=5\\
t_2&=10.5\\
t_3&=26.25\\
t_4&=62.625
\end{align}
$$

I need to solve my recurrence equation for $n$ when $t_n=13\times10^{10}$. How can I achieve this in mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RSolve` can provide an exact expression for `t[n]`

```
Clear[t];

t[n_] = t[n] /. RSolve[{t[1] == 5, t[2] == 21/2,
       t[3] == 105/4, t[4] == 501/8,
       t[n] == (5 t[n - 1] - 3 t[n - 4])/2},
      t[n], n][[1]] // ToRadicals // Simplify
```

> (1/219)*(2^(1 - n)*
>           (1 + (10 - Sqrt[73])^(1/3) + 
>                (10 + Sqrt[73])^(1/3))^n*
>           (73 + (73*(5767 - 520*Sqrt[73]))^(1/3) + 
>              (73*(5767 + 520*Sqrt[73]))^(1/3)) + 
>         ((1/4)*(2 + (-1 - I*Sqrt[3])*
>                     (10 - Sqrt[73])^(1/3) + 
>                   I*(I + Sqrt[3])*(10 + Sqrt[73])^
>                       (1/3)))^n*(146 + I*(I + Sqrt[3])*
>                (73*(5767 - 520*Sqrt[73]))^(1/3) + 
>              (-1 - I*Sqrt[3])*
>                (73*(5767 + 520*Sqrt[73]))^(1/3)) + 
>         ((1/4)*(2 + I*(I + Sqrt[3])*
>                     (10 - Sqrt[73])^(1/3) + 
>                   (-1 - I*Sqrt[3])*(10 + Sqrt[73])^
>                       (1/3)))^n*(146 + (-1 - I*Sqrt[3])*
>                (73*(5767 - 520*Sqrt[73]))^(1/3) + 
>              I*(I + Sqrt[3])*
>                (73*(5767 + 520*Sqrt[73]))^(1/3)))

```
Table[t[n], {n, 0, 5}] // N // Rationalize
```

> {2, 5, 21/2, 105/4, 501/8, 2385/16}

```
FindRoot[t[n] == 13*^10, {n, 25}][[1]] // Chop // Quiet
```

> n -> 28.6241

```
(t[#] // Chop) & /@ {28., 29.}
```

> {7.54702*10^10, 1.80385*10^11}

```
LogPlot[{t[n] // Chop, 13*^10}, {n, 28, 29}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
t[1] = 5;
t[2] = 10.5;
t[3] = 26.25;
t[4] = 62.625;
t[n_Integer] := 2.5 t[n - 1] - 1.5 t[n - 4];

n = 5; While[t[n] < 13 10^10, Null; n++]; n
```

(* 29 *)